# Is it possible to replace an existing pip package with specific name by my own package?

Tags: pypi

I would like to add my package to pip installer with a specific name, however, somebody else has created a similar module with the same name and it is not maintained anymore by them. 
Is it possible to take somehow the name of an existing module? I ask because the name I wanted to use is very descriptive and so it would be nice to use it for the module.

Comment: No, it's not. Think about what would happen if that *was* possible: I could publish a new version of e.g. `requests` that either did something completely different or, worse, *seemed* to do the same thing but also had some nefarious purpose (e.g. stealing credentials). I think we can all agree that this would not be ideal.

Comment: Thanks. The same thing came on my mind, just thinking whether there is some process which cleans packages that are not maintained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, under some conditions:

> **How do I claim an abandoned or previously registered project name?**
>
> Follow the ["How to request a name transfer"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0541/#how-to-request-a-name-transfer) section of PEP 541.

-- https://pypi.org/help/#project-name-claim